# How to avoid updating Angular form value on validation fail

Tags: angular, angular-forms

Given a formControl and a custom validator function, is there a way to stop updating the current formControl value if the validation fails?

e.g. I have a file input formControl, when a file is selected, my custom validator will check the file type, if it is of the target file type, update the formControl value to the file object as normal. If it is clicked again and choose an incorrect type of file, DON'T update the formControl value (i.e. leave the correct file object there).

I tried checking the file type in my custom validator, which works, but the formControl value is updated anyway, although the form becomes invalid.

Comment: That's not very user friendly : if your user chooses a new file, you should only validate the said file, and not keep the previous one. But if you still want to do so, you can use a simple cache system that will store the last valid file in a variable of your component class.

Comment: Validation is for the sake of telling the user that field's not correct and to prevent form submit.